# How to check if my software is 32-bit or 64-bit

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I want to check if my **software** is 64 bit or 32 bit (not the OS). This software is an **executable** file, and when I check it, no information is given if it is 64-bit or 32-bit.

How do I check if my software is 64-bit or 32-bit?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the `file` command to check out what format has that executable. For example:

```
file /usr/bin/gedit
/usr/bin/gedit: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0x5a388215eb6f60b420fc3b6d68ec52d563071f84, stripped
```

Answer (score 4):

This simple command will show you whether the executable file is  32 bit(i386) or 64 bit(amd64) .

Syntax:

```
apt-cache show $(dpkg -S /path/to/the/file | awk -F ':' '{print $1 }') | awk '/Architecture:/ {print $2}' -
```

Example:

```
$ apt-cache show $(dpkg -S /usr/bin/gedit | awk -F ':' '{print $1 }') | awk '/Architecture:/ {print $2}' -
amd64
```

Explanation:

`dpkg -S` command grabs the package in which the file actually belongs to.`apt-cache show package` command will shows the details about the package.From that details, awk grabs only the Architecture part and redirects it to stdout.

**OR**

You can try this command also,

```
$ dpkg -l $(dpkg -S /usr/bin/gedit | awk -F ':' '{print $1 }') | awk '/ii/ {print $4}'
amd64
```

Comment: `cut -d: -f1` would be shorter here, and note that this only works for installed packages, not some random file in your home folder. Perhaps `xargs -r` is more appropriate in case the `dpkg -S` command returns empty.

Comment: This only works if the software came from apt/dpkg, while the other answer always works no matter where it came from.