# pipe to file command

Tags: command-line, pipe, file-command

I wanted to know the [bitness](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437857/how-to-check-if-my-software-is-32-bit-or-64-bit) of a certain software (omc), so I ran first

```
which omc
file /usr/bin/omc
```

and that gave me all information I needed.
Before telling my colleagues, I wanted to shorten it to a single line:

```
which omc | file
```

but that did not work. But why not?

Comment: `which omc | xargs file`, as the accepted answer says. Or, you could also do: `file "$(which omc)"`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I searched for similar questions, but `which` and `file` don't make good search terms...

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5782/107266